# Loss goes down but never below a certain treshold

Tags: neural-networks, loss

I made a neural network in C#, I observe the loss goes down but never below a certain treshold.

**This is XOR function error graph:**
(The graph is every 4 samples, so for all the 4 possible combinations of inputs there is one combination that performs better (MIN) and one that perform worse (MAX error)

[image]

**NN architecture:**

- 4 layers
- Number of neurons (2,6,6,1)
- First 3 layers ReLU activated (He initi), last layer Sigmoid (Glorot Init)
- Epochs 5000 (20.000 samples)
- Learning rate: 0.02

**Encoding**

- One is encoded as 0.5
- Zero is encoded as -0.5

The function is almost working, in the sense it outputs almost 0 instead of -0.5 and it outputs almost 0.5 in place of 0.5.. So if I decode the input with the following

**Decoding**

- One if output is > 0.25
- Zer if output is < 0.25

it has 100% accuracy.. however since it was trained with -0.5 as encoded zero actually it is not outputting what I expect.

---

**The second example is from MNIST:**

[image]

**NN architecture:**

- Number of layers 3
- Number of neurons (784,128,10)
- All activations Sigmoid with Glorot initialization
- Learning rate 0.005
- Epochs 1 (the graph refers to 40% of the first epoch)

**Encoding:**

- 784 pixels encoded with grey values mapped from (0,255) to (0,1)
- 10 channels in output where the output is set to 1 for corresponding digit.

Even though the error rapidly decrease at the beginning, it gets stuck, and the accuracy stuck aroun 11% (slightly better than guessing the correct digit)

---

So what are the possible causes for error staying above a certain treshold?

Code: https://github.com/Darelbi/NeuraSharp/tree/main/NeuraSharp/NeuraSharp.BuiltIn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, Sigmoid activation cannot go below 0.  Either modify your encoding or switch to a different activation (tanh for example can go to -1).

On the second issue, it is customary to use softmax activation on the outputs here which ensures all outputs sum to 1 and it can vaguely be interpreted as the network's estimated probability distribution over class (1 being 100% surity, .5 being 50%, so on).  This is not strictly necessary so you might also be looking at underfitting.  But I'd start with softmax and go from there.

Comment: Ok, It worked, for the softmax It was not necessary since i was already taking the max output lane. Turns out i swapped Sigmoid for tanh (Remembering It was Sigmoid in range -1,1). For First problem I reached 100% accuracy with  expected values. For second problema It was definitely underfitting. Now i reach accuracy 81% with some noise, I consider It great improvement. Thank you